# How to aggregate values within array in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

> Spark version 3.0

I have a dataframe like this

```py
+-------------------------------------------------+
|named_val                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|[[Alex, 1], [is, 1], [a, 1], [good, 1], [boy, 1]]|
|[[Bob, 1], [Bob, 1], [bad, 1], [Bob, 1]]         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to create a map with count of unique values as shown below

Expected output

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|named_val                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|{Alex->1, is->1, a->1, good->1, boy->1}          |
|{Bob->3, bad->1}                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

To reproduce the code use

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([([['Alex', 1], ['is', 1], ['a', 1], ['good', 1], ['boy', 1]],),([['Bob', 1], ['Bob', 1], ['bad', 1], ['Bob', 1]],)],['named_val'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about our old friend UDF? se/de cost should be low in comparison to shuffling:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def sum_merge(ar):
  d = dict()
  for i in ar:
    k, v = i[0], int(i[1])    
    d[k] = d[k] + v if k in d else v
  return d

sum_merge_udf = udf(sum_merge)

df.select(sum_merge_udf("named_val").alias("named_val"))

# +----------------------------------+
# |named_val                         |
# +----------------------------------+
# |{a=1, Alex=1, is=1, boy=1, good=1}|
# |{bad=1, Bob=3}                    |
# +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: need suggestions here...UDF are considered as black box for spark as they can't be benefited from catalyst optimizer.. so in case of large dataset what should be considered? Will post performance results soon

Comment: yes is comes with the cost of serialization/deserialization although the last versions of PySpark have done significant improvements towards that direction.  Although that cost will be much lower than any shuffle since we still keep the narrow transformations. The optimal case would be this `df.withColumn("new_map", expr("aggregate(named_val, map(), (acc, i) -> map_concat(acc, map(i[0], element_at(acc, i[0]) + i[0])))"))` which I didn't manage to make it work. Maybe is a challenge for someone else ;)

Comment: I was also struggling with higher order functions to make it work but no luck with solution....will update the performance matrix using this udf

Comment: yes it is true you should always try with built-in functions before ending up to UDFs although some times they consist the only solution

Comment: i have been trying with no success too.. i will resort to udf as well :)

Comment: did you try the same approach with aggregate @anky or another one?

Comment: @abiratsis yes with aggregate (various ways :D) , wasn't able to to so.

Comment: @anky and `map_concat` doesn't really merge right? It returns multiple items in fact, I am not really sure if that's an expected behaviour but I can guess that not, it should return one merged map

Comment: @anky in fact I have realized that `merge_concat` allows identical keys, for instance will not replace them. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398999/merge-maps-in-scala-dataframe/61405371#61405371) I faced the same issue

Comment: it does for seperate arrays though i am not sure how it would work here. may be when i get some free time I will play more, you can too and let me know(would be interested )

Comment: sure I will, please do the same

Answer (score 2):

In scala, but python version will be very similar:

```
val df =  Seq(Seq(("Alex",1),("is",1),("a",1),("good",1),("boy",1)),Seq(("Bob",1),("Bob",1),("bad",1),("Bob",1))).toDF()
df.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------+
|value                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|[[Alex, 1], [is, 1], [a, 1], [good, 1], [boy, 1]]|
|[[Bob, 1], [Bob, 1], [bad, 1], [Bob, 1]]         |
+-------------------------------------------------+


df.withColumn("id",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
.select('id,explode('value))
.select('id,'col.getField("_1").as("val"))
.groupBy('id,'val).agg(count('val).as("ct"))
.select('id,map('val,'ct).as("map"))
.groupBy('id).agg(collect_list('map))
.show(false)

+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|id |collect_list(map)                                          |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|0  |[[is -> 1], [Alex -> 1], [boy -> 1], [a -> 1], [good -> 1]]|
|1  |[[bad -> 1], [Bob -> 3]]                                   |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```